# snapshotChanges() streaming multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

The current fonction fetch documents (`lobbies`) in my Firestore database given name and password properties:

```
getLobbyByNameAndPassword(name: string, password: string): Observable<Lobby[]> {
    const lobbiesRef =
      this.afs.collection('lobbies', ref => ref.where('name', '==', name)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Lobby;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
        }));
    return lobbiesRef.pipe(
      map((res) => {
        return res.filter(item => item.password === password);
      })
    );
  }
```

I'm using `snapshotChanges()` to extract the `id` of the documents as explained in the official git repo [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/7eb3e51022c7381dfc94ffb9e12555065f060639/docs/firestore/collections.md#example). But I added `pipe` function because I guess it is required now with the newer version of RxJS. Then I just implement another pipe to filter the results.

The problem is when I subscribe to this `Observable`, it is called multiple times, non stop.

Any idea why?

Comment: I think your observable emits many signals, if you interested in only one you may use first operator or take(1) rxjs operator

Comment: Indeed, it works. Any idea why it emits that many signals?

Comment: I am not familiar with firebase, but as I see it in your example in GitHub, there is "|async" pipe used. So I have the assumption that "many signals" are expected behavior and the source observable emits new signal any time the data is updated. Once again it is just my assumption.